# How to transfer additional object in functor for std::priority_queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, functor

I have my struct:

```
struct S{
    int a;    
};
```

And i have class:

```
class Other{
    //some fields
};
```

I need write functor:

```
struct Comparator {
    bool operator()(S& l, S& r) {
     //some code, considered l,r and any object of class Other
    }
};
```

In operator () should be considered any object of class Other.
How to transfer object into functor?
I use functor for priority_queue.
Object of class Other can't be statical field.

Another ways for this purpose?

Comment: need more information

Answer (score 2):

Make `Comparator` store an object of type `Other`(or reference, `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` depending on the ownership and validity semantics), and pass this in through `Comparator`'s constructor.

```
struct Comparator {
    Comparator(const Other& val) : mVal(val){}
    bool operator()(S& l, S& r)
    {
     //Comparison code here uses l, r and mVal
    }

    private:
    Other mVal;
};
```

Create the [`priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) like this, assuming you want to use `vector<T>` as the underlying container:

```
Other otherToHelpCompare;
Comparator myComparator{otherToHelpCompare};
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Comparator> q{myComparator};
```